# Facebook: Additional links on left nav, are they apps?

Tags: facebook

We are wanting to add additional links that contains information/media to the left hand link list. E.g: http://www.facebook.com/sdabocconi

Does anyone know if these are custom built apps added to the sidebar item, or something else?  How are they added to that sidebar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are [custom page tabs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/#tabs), which can be apps, or an external site on iframes (from the developer blog: [Introducing iframe Tabs for Pages](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/462/))